# Consulta sobre c# mvvm wpf comunicación entre dos views y un viewmodel (con codigo)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hola gente buenas tardes? soy novato en c# wpf y mvvm. Queria consultar a ver donde estoy errando tengo dos views (supongamos uno es tipo factura con detalles y el otro view es por si queremos buscar clientes por ej por nombre apellido) que apuntan a un solo viewmodel. cada uno por separado funciona bien el tema es cuando tengo los dos abierto y busco un cliente al salir de este view no me actualiza la info de otro por mas que es el mismo viewmodel y notificando las propiedades necesarias.

En que le estoy errando, como lo trabajan? con dos views o utilizan un control de usuario,etc?

Desde ya muchas gracias por sus molestias y Saludos

Paso el viewmodel

```
class LoadPlaysVM : ValidatableModel
{

    public LoadPlaysVM()
    {
        this.RefreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.GetData);
        this.SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveCore);
        this.NewCommand = new DelegateCommand(New);
        this.DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(Delete);
        this.CancelCommand = new DelegateCommand(Cancel);
        this.RefreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(GetData);
        this.EditCommand = new DelegateCommand(Edit);
        this.AceptFindCustomerCommand = new DelegateCommand(AceptFindCustomer);
        IsEditable = false;
    }

    public DelegateCommand NewCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand EditCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand RefreshCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand CancelCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand AceptFindCustomerCommand { get; private set; }

    private LoadPlays _items;
    public  LoadPlays Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        protected set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    private DetailLoadPlays _selectedItem;
    public DetailLoadPlays SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem == value) return;

            _selectedItem = value;

            // Update bindings, no broadcast
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    private List<DetailLoadPlays> _itemsDetail;
    public List<DetailLoadPlays> ItemsDetail
    {
        get { return _itemsDetail; }
        protected set
        {
            _itemsDetail = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemsDetail");
        }
    }
    public void GetData()
    {            
        using (LotterySystemDb db = new LotterySystemDb())
        {               
            Items = db.LoadPlays.Include(b => b.DetailLoadPlays).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == Items.Id);                
            ItemsDetail = Items.DetailLoadPlays.ToList();              
        }         
    }

    protected void LoadDataRelation()
    {            
        using (LotterySystemDb db = new LotterySystemDb())
        {                               
           db.LoadPlays.Where(l => l.Id == Id).Include(b => b.DetailLoadPlays);                
        }
    }

    protected virtual void New()
    {
        using (LotterySystemDb db = new LotterySystemDb())
        {            
            DetailLoadPlays entity = new DetailLoadPlays();                
            this.Items.DetailLoadPlays.Add(entity);                
            ItemsDetail = Items.DetailLoadPlays.ToList();
            this.SelectedItem = entity;
            this.IsEditable = true;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Cancel()
    {
        this.IsEditable = false;

        if (SelectedItem.Id == 0)
        {
            // El  registro es nuevo, nunca fue  guardado, se descarta:
            this.Items.DetailLoadPlays.Remove(SelectedItem);
            ItemsDetail.Remove(SelectedItem);
            this.SelectedItem = this.Items.DetailLoadPlays.LastOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            // El registro es un registro guardado que estaba siendo editado,
            //se descartan los cambios del Model y se vuelve a mostrar la info del SelectedItem                
        }
    }

    protected void SaveCore()
    {
        using (LotterySystemDb db = new LotterySystemDb())
        {
            if (this.SelectedItem.Id == 0)
            {             
                Items.DetailLoadPlays.Add(SelectedItem);                 
                SelectedItem.LoadPlaysId = Items.Id;
                db.DetailLoadPlays.Add(SelectedItem);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
                foreach (var e in Items.DetailLoadPlays)
                {
                    db.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }                    
        }
        IsEditable = false;
    }

    protected void Delete()
    {
        using (LotterySystemDb db = new LotterySystemDb())
        {
            db.Entry(SelectedItem).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            db.SaveChanges();         
            ItemsDetail.Remove(SelectedItem);
            this.SelectedItem = Items.DetailLoadPlays.LastOrDefault();                
        }
        IsEditable = false;
    }

    private bool _isEditable;
    public bool IsEditable
    {
        get { return _isEditable; }
        set
        {
            _isEditable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsEditable");

            this.CancelCommand.IsEnabled = value;
            this.SaveCommand.IsEnabled = value;

            this.NewCommand.IsEnabled = !value;
            this.EditCommand.IsEnabled = !value;
            this.RefreshCommand.IsEnabled = !value;
            this.DeleteCommand.IsEnabled = !value && this.SelectedItem != null && this.SelectedItem.Id != 0;

            if (value)
                this.OnModelValidationRequested();
        }
    }

    protected virtual async void Edit()
    {
        if (SelectedItem != null)
        {
            using (LotterySystemDb db = new LotterySystemDb())
            {
                await db.LoadPlays.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == SelectedItem.Id);
                IsEditable = true;
            }
        }
    }


    private int? _tempId;
    public int? tempId
    {
        get { return _tempId; }
        set
        {
            if (_tempId == value) return;
            _tempId = value;
            using (var db = new LotterySystemDb())
            {

                //Customer _customer = null;
                _customer = db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == tempId);
                //var result = db.Customer.Where(x => x.Code == tempId);
                if (_customer != null)
                {
                    Items = db.LoadPlays.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == _customer.Id);
                    if (Items != null)
                    {                            
                        GetData();
                    }
                }
                OnPropertyChanged("tempId");
                OnPropertyChanged("CustomerId");
            }
        }
    }

    //Metodo que verifica si la validacion de los registros es correcta y habilita el comando SAVE
    protected void OnModelValidationRequested()
    {
        if (!this.IsEditable)
            return;
        this.SaveCommand.IsEnabled = !HasErrors;
    }

    private Customer _customer;
    protected Customer Customer
    {
        get { return _customer; }
        set
        {
            _customer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Customer");
        }
    }

    private List<Customer> _customerList;
    public List<Customer> CustomerList
    {
        get { return _customerList; }
        set
        {
            _customerList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CustomerList");
        }
    }


    private string _searchCustomer;
    public string SearchCustomer
    {
        get { return _searchCustomer; }
        set
        {
            if (_searchCustomer == value) return;
            _searchCustomer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchCustomer");
            if (_searchCustomer == null)
            { return; }
            else
            {
                using (var db = new LotterySystemDb())
                {
                    var query = from c in db.Customer where c.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchCustomer.ToLower()) select c;
                    var data = query.ToList();
                    CustomerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(data).ToList();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Customer _selectedcustomer;
    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return _selectedcustomer; }
        set
        {
            _selectedcustomer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
        }
    }
    public void AceptFindCustomer()
    {
        if (this.SelectedCustomer != null)
            { _customer = SelectedCustomer;
            using (var db = new LotterySystemDb())
            {
                Items = db.LoadPlays.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == _customer.Id);
            }
            if (Items != null)
            {
                GetData();
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("CustomerId");
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemsDetail");
      }
```

El view principal

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"  Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 2 10 2"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <!-- <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>-->

</Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F3" Command="{Binding NewCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F4" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F6" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F7" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F8" Command="{Binding Find}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>

<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <!-- IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"> -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Cliente:"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Model.CustomerId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedItem="{Binding Model.Id}" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <!-- <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding CustomerList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedItem="{Binding Model.CustomerId}" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/> -->
        <TextBox Grid.Row ="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding tempId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="85"/>
        <Button Name="FindCustomer" Grid.Row ="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="Buscar Cliente" Click="FindCustomer_Click" Width="80"/>
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Button Content="Listar Todos (F2)" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Nuevo (F3)" Command="{Binding NewCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Editar (F4)" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Guardar (F5)" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Cancelar (F6)" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Eliminar (F7)" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Total, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="85"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <DataGrid Name="Grid"  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsDetail,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Height="100"/>

        <Label Content="Code:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Code, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <Label Content="Categoria Games Id:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.GameCategoryId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <Label Content="Categoria Games Descripcion:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.GameCategoryDescription, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <Label Content="Catidad:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Quantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <Label Content="Precio Unitario:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.UnitAmount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

El view buscador

```
    <DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <!-- IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"> -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"
                              DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SearchCustomer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Buscar" Command="{Binding FindCommand}"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Aceptar" Command="{Binding AceptFindCustomerCommand}" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
  <!--  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}"/>-->
    <DataGrid Name="Grid"  ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Este es el LoadPLaysView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class LoadPlaysView : Window
{
 LoadPlaysVM _LoadPlaysVM;
    FindCustomerView _FindCustomerView;
    public LoadPlaysView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _LoadPlaysVM = new LoadPlaysVM();
        this.DataContext = _LoadPlaysVM;        
    }

    private void FindCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _FindCustomerView = new FindCustomerView();
        _FindCustomerView.Show();
    }
}
```

El FindCustomerView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class FindCustomerView : Window
{     
    LoadPlaysVM _LoadPlaysVM;
    public FindCustomerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _LoadPlaysVM = new LoadPlaysVM();
        this.DataContext = _LoadPlaysVM;
    }
}
```

Comment: como estas asignando el ViewModel a los DataContext de los Views?

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye lo que has puesto en el comentario

Comment: Se que no es lo mejor pero aun no vi el locator, y tambien se que hago mal en colocar el boton para abrir otro view aca pero bueno queria realizar las pruebas y no perder tiempo para ver si funcionaba.
Saludos

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye el codigo que has puesto en el comentario

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, el otro view es casi igual

Comment: Supongo que LoadPLaysView es el View principal, y como defines el DataContext del View buscador?

Comment: Que es el View buscardor? un UserControl? Page? Window?

Comment: El view buscador es un windows.
Correcto el LoadPLaysView es el principal
El datacontext del buscador es igual al del loadplays (cambiando el nombre por public FindCustomerView())
 y sin el FindCustomer_Clic.......

Comment: Bueno, si la declaracion del buscador es igual al de LoadPlaysViews, entonces estas creando dos instancias de LoadPlaysVM

Comment: Por favor agrega la declaracion del buscador solo para confirmar y poder darte una respuesta

Comment: Ahi le agregue el FindCustomer tambien al codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas creando una instancia de LoadPlaysVM para cada View, es decir, cada View tiene su LoadPlaysVM de manera independiente, cuando el objetivo es que ambas Views se enlacen a la misma instancia de LoadPlaysVM

```
public partial class LoadPlaysView : Window
{
  LoadPlaysVM _LoadPlaysVM;
  FindCustomerView _FindCustomerView;

  public LoadPlaysView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    _LoadPlaysVM = new LoadPlaysVM(); //******AQUI ESTAS CREANDO UNA INSTANCIA
    this.DataContext = _LoadPlaysVM;        
  }

 ...
}

public partial class FindCustomerView : Window
{     
  LoadPlaysVM _LoadPlaysVM;
  public FindCustomerView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    _LoadPlaysVM = new LoadPlaysVM();//******AQUI ESTAS CREANDO OTRA INSTANCIA
    this.DataContext = _LoadPlaysVM;
  }
}
```

Como solucion, te sugiero que crees una unica instancia de LoadPlaysVM y le enlaces ambos views, para esto, necesitas que ambos Views puedan ver a LoadPlaysVM.

Exactamente como vas a hacer esto? Depende de como tengas organizado tu proyecto, puedes ponerlo en una clase estatica global, en App.xaml.cs, o puedes crear un ViewModel para MainWindow y declarar alli tu unica instancia de LoadPlaysVM.

Por ejemplo

```
//DECLARA ESTO UNA SOLA VEZ EN TU PROGRAMA Y PONLO DONDE TUS CLASES PUEDAN VERLO

public LoadPlaysVM _LoadPlaysVM = new LoadPlaysVM();

/*********************************************/
public partial class LoadPlaysView : Window
{

 FindCustomerView _FindCustomerView;

 public LoadPlaysView()
 {
  InitializeComponent();

  this.DataContext = _LoadPlaysVM; //LA MISMA Y UNICA INSTANCIA
 }

...
```

}

```
public partial class FindCustomerView : Window
{     

  public FindCustomerView()
  {
   InitializeComponent();

   this.DataContext = _LoadPlaysVM;//LA MISMA Y UNICA INSTANCIA
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola y gracias nuevamente @Tuco por responder, recien llego y veo tu corrección, mañana lo voy a probar con la indicaciones que me das y ver si puedo solucionarlo, pero seguramente con lo que indicas y viendo la logica ese es el problema.
Gracias a todos por responder y aportar soluciones e ideas.
Saludos
Fede

Comment: Recien me pongo a probarlo porque a la mañana trabajo con lineas de media tension en una cooperativa electrica.

Si lo pongo como me indicas arriba tanto en el App.xaml.cs o LoadPlaysView.xaml.cs me da error:
public LoadPlaysVM _LoadPlaysVM = new LoadPlaysVM();
Error en el _LoadPlaysVM con la indicación "un espacio de nombres no puede contener directamente miembros como campos o metodos"

Pero la solución que me indicaste seguro es la correcta ahora me pondré a ver como crear una sola instancia para los dos view y seguro que sale funcionando.

Gracias por tus molestias.
Saludos
Fede

Comment: Aprobechandome de sus conocimientos ( @Tuco y demas) vale la pena utilizar un framework como prism o MVVM Light u otro. SI es asi cual recomiendan. 
Yo no utilizo ningo y tal vez uno me solucione mas de un problema a lidiar.

Comment: Yo nunca he usado frameworks para MVVM, si alguien los hizo es porque alguna ventaja han de tener, pero nunca he tenido la necesidad de uno. Antes de usar un framework primero me gusta familiarizarme con la tecnologia subyacente, es decir, no aprendo MVVM si no domino las reglas basicas de WPF, como el XAML y el Binding, No aprendo PRISM si no estoy bien entrenado en MVVM. No uso Entity Framework si no se usar SQL, Angular - Javascript, etc. Ademas creo que Prism ya no lo mantiene Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft le pasa Prism a desarrolladores independientes https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/03/19/prism-grows-up/

Comment: Gracias nuevamente @tuco por responder, yo creo lo mismo por eso aun no he usado ninguno. Pero por ahi alguien sabia si valia la pena...pero como decis debe ser bueno pero primero saber las cosas hacerla por uno mismo.  
Si encuentro como instanciar el viewmodel para los dos view lo comento aca.  
Saludos.